# How do I prevent the delay when mapping jj to <ESC> in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, escape

I've recently mapped `jj` to `<ESC>` in insert mode for quick escaping. While everything is functional, I find the brief delay after typing `j` while it waits for a second input very distracting.

Is it possible for a `j` to always be instantly inserted into the buffer, then if I press `j` again the first one is removed before returning to normal mode?

Do I need to use some sort of script for this? I've tried fiddling with the `timeoutlength` and `ttimeoutlength` options but they don't seem to do what I want.

Comment: While I understand you point, I couldn't reproduce it. Can you try with `vim -Nu NONE` ?

Comment: @nobe4 I feel stupid now, assumed this was the default behaviour with vim but it's actually a problem with the vim emulator in my IDE. Don't think it's fixable, but thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: When in doubt, always try from scratch vim :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `<nowait>` to map command, which will prevent this delay. It will instantly leave insert mode as soon as the second `j` is pressed, as well as remove initially typed `j`. Also if you need to type literal "jj", you'd need to wait a bit, but it's very rare.   Also you won't be able to map something like `jjj` as it won't wait for any character after `jj` (which is probably ok for most).  See `:help map-nowait` for more information.

```
inoremap <nowait> jj <ESC>
```

- `<nowait>` was added in Vim version 7.3.1261

Comment: I think it is not what the OP want. He wants no delay after pressing first `j`. But I think it is inevitable unless you reduce `timeoutlen` to very small values.

Comment: There's no perceived delay after pressing the first `j` as `j` is inserted immediately, and one can continue typing without waiting as there's no pause or anything.  There's a visual cue, ie "j" appears on bottom right briefly